# Why does my network connections history tell me I have had a wired connection?

Tags: networking, internet

It says, 2 days ago that I have had a wired connection. Why is it telling me that when I have not used an Ethernet cable ?

When I googled this, nothing came up, except people asking questions about problems with Internet connection. I'm having no trouble with connecting.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing, its just some updated drivers  testing the devices and ports. A connection log can be created if there is only upsignal . Its nothing to worry about.